# Show solution name in menu bar in full screen Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When having Visual studio (2017) in full screen (shift-alt-enter) the solution's name is not visible. Has anyone found a way to append it to the menu?

### [image: Example of solution name in menu bar.]

One can open the solution explorer and scroll to the top but I would like to be able to see the solution's name without manual interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a plugin to do something similar.

[Meet file path on footer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.FilePathOnFooter). This plugin, will display the full path of your file (that includes your solution) and works of course even while on fullscreen mode. Plus, you got an easy way to visit the folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the solution name in the solution explorer, then clean the solution and rebuild it and it should show up there.
2. We are experiencing an outage in the South Central region right now,
   which may very well be the cause of your issue.

[image]

You can check the [Azure Status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) page for updates.